# Convert date from GMT timezone to local time zone -- using ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME

Tags: java, date, gmt, java.util.date, java-time

I have a date, assumed to be in GMT, which I want to convert to local time zone using the ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME formatting.

Basically, I want to go from:

2018-03-13 03:00:00.0

to:

2018-03-13T00:00:00-09:00

Obviously this would change, depending on your local time zone.

Any ideas on how I could do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can leverage `ZonedDateTime` for this. You just need to read in the date as UTC and convert it as needed. You might get something like this:

```
String readPattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S";
DateTimeFormatter readDateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(readPattern).withZone(ZoneOffset.UTC);
LocalDateTime utcLocalDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-03-13 03:00:00.0", readDateTimeFormatter);
ZonedDateTime localZonedDateTime = utcLocalDateTime.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC).atZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.systemDefault());
String writePattern = "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ssXXX";
DateTimeFormatter writeDateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(writePattern);
System.out.println(writeDateTimeFormatter.format(localZonedDateTime));
```

For more info, see:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html

Comment: This Answer is not bad but has some issues. It could use a bit more discussion/explanation. And, I suggest breaking it up into two phases, parsing the input, then applying the `ZoneOffset`.

Comment: Since you are parsing as a `LocalDateTime` (no zone or offset), there is no need to call `withZone` on your `DateTimeFormatter`. Does not add value to this example.

Comment: `ZonedDateTime` is not appropriate here. When using a mere offset-from-UTC rather than a time zone, use the `OffsetDateTime` class, as the name suggests.

Comment: Your last two lines are confusing and tangled. You should be working with time zones at that point, not an offset. Call `ZoneId.systemDefault`. All of your code could be replaced by one line: `LocalDateTime.parse( "2018-01-23 01:23:45".replace( " " , "T" ) ).atOffset( ZoneOffset.UTC ).atZoneSameInstant( ZoneId.systemDefault()  )`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Your basic idea is right, and @BasilBourque has already offered some good suggestions for improvement. Allow me to add that `SSS` is requiring three decimals on the second, and the example string in the question has only one. So use only one `S`.

Comment: @BasilBourque How would I get this into OffsetDateTime, as you suggested?  Your one liner is suitable for ZonedDateTime

Comment: Greatly appreciate all your help!  Simply convert to OffsetDateTime by calling .toOffsetDateTime()

Comment: @user1655963 Better to stay with a `ZonedDateTime` if you know the intended time zone. A zone is always preferable over a mere offset. If your concern is generating a string in your desired format with an offset indicator, stick with `ZonedDateTime` and use `DateTimeFormatter` to generate text in any format you wish.

Comment: @BasilBourque the same is essentially accomplished by first converting to a ZonedDateTime and then creating a OffsetDateTime using .toOffsetDateTime() How would you have gone about using the DateTimeFormatter to remove the unwanted text from the ZonedDateTime?

Answer (score 1):

### Parse the date-time string into `LocalDateTime`:

```
DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m:s.S", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-03-13 03:00:00.0", dtf);
```

### Combine this with UTC offset to create an `OffsetDateTime`:

```
OffsetDateTime odtUtc = ldt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
```

### Create its copy with offset set as -09:00 while keeping the instant same:

```
OffsetDateTime odtUtcMinus9 = odtUtc.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.of("+09:00"));
```

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.OffsetDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneOffset;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m:s.S", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-03-13 03:00:00.0", dtf);
        System.out.println(ldt); // 2018-03-13T03:00

        OffsetDateTime odtUtc = ldt.atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC);
        System.out.println(odtUtc); // 2018-03-13T03:00Z

        OffsetDateTime odtUtcMinus9 = odtUtc.withOffsetSameInstant(ZoneOffset.of("+09:00"));
        System.out.println(odtUtcMinus9); // 2018-03-13T12:00+09:00
    }
}
```

Note that the timezone offset is a fixed thing i.e. it is independent of the [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time). If you are looking for an automatic adjustment of timezone offset as per the DST, use [`ZonedDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/ZonedDateTime.html). The methods are very much similar to what we have used in the last demo.

**Demo:**

```
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.ZoneId;
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtf = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d H:m:s.S", Locale.ENGLISH);
        LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse("2018-03-13 03:00:00.0", dtf);
        System.out.println(ldt); // 2018-03-13T03:00

        ZonedDateTime zdtUtc = ldt.atZone(ZoneId.of("Etc/UTC"));
        System.out.println(zdtUtc); // 2018-03-13T03:00Z[Etc/UTC]

        ZonedDateTime zdtAmericaAdak = zdtUtc.withZoneSameInstant(ZoneId.of("America/Adak"));
        System.out.println(zdtAmericaAdak); // 2018-03-12T18:00-09:00[America/Adak]

        // A custom format
        DateTimeFormatter dtfOutput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String formatted = dtfOutput.format(zdtAmericaAdak);
        System.out.println(formatted); // 2018-03-12 18:00:00.000-09:00
    }
}
```

Learn more about `java.time`, the [modern date-time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-date-time.html)<sup>*</sup> from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>